# JMeter graphics results data sample not clustered if there is not smiple loop

Tags: jmeter

Learning JMeter. Question about Graph results:

**Scénario 1:**

```
 1 thread group user count=500
    simple loop count = 1
      Graph result: 
        showing 49509ms max which I don't understand
        Data samples points are lined up, not clustered
```

**Scénario 2:**

```
 1 thread group, user count 1
    simple loop count = 500
      Graph result:
        max is 2008ms, which is ok
        Data samples points (black) are well clustered like in the tutorial
```

Does this mean that we have to have a simple loop to get a correct drawing ?

Scenario 1: (data samples not clustered ?)

[image]

Scenario 2: (seems correct)

[image]

Comment: There's no such thing as "correct drawing". What's the goal of your test? Was it to test concurrent users (in which case scenario 1 is right). Or was your goal to test how application handles 100 sequential requests from the same user (which is what scenario 2 does)? If you wanted to know how application behaves with 100 concurrent users, so your answer is: not very well. And graph matches that answer. Although it's unusual to perform 1 iteration, you need a sample of at least 100, if not 1000 to draw any conclusion.

Comment: The question is more about the drawings. Since the test is to hit the same MVC route 500 times. Why are they so different ? Where,s the 85201ms coming from ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this mean that we have to have a simple loop to get a correct drawing ?

**Short Answer:** A Big No. We simulate the scenario based on our performance goals which are derived from SLA.

**Long Answer:**

Your Test Plan primarily depends on following parameters (based on SLA):

1. Anticipated load (how many users does your application must support) - decides the number of threads.
2. type of test (load/stress/spike etc) - decides Ramp-up/Ramp-down pattern
3. test duration - decides Loop Count
4. user mix (different types of users. eg: admin, manager, admin, normal user etc.)
5. Transaction mix (critical transactions to cover)

so, prepare the test plan based on the requirements.

Your requirements are your INPUTs but not graphs. Graphs are end results, which are used to analyze the application performance after the test w.r.t. Key Performance Indicators (KPI) like Response time, Throughput, Server Resource Utilization etc.

---

Coming to both the graphs (scenarios), It is well-expected behavior.

In Scenario 1 (500 users): User will be sending the requests parallelly to the server. so, the server is busy responding to all those requests, which eventually results in HIGH response times (`49509ms`).

In scenario 2 (1 user): Only one user is sending the requests sequentially (once response comes for the previous request, then only next request will be sent). so, the server has sufficient resources to handle a single request, which results in low response times (`2008ms`). But, In the real world, no one will deploy their applications for a single user.

Total `85201ms` suggests, you are grouping more than one request under `transaction controller`, which sums up all the samplers response time, to give the overall response time for all the samplers.

If a Transaction Controller has `n` samplers:

sampler1 RT + sampler2 RT + sampler3 RT + .... + sampler N RT = Transaction Controller RT. (RT - response time)

References:

1. http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-web-test-plan.html
2. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb924356.aspx